# Failed to locate the main schema resource

Tags: magento2

I tried to upload the product view with my own catalog_product_view.xml in:

app/desing/frontend/{Name}/{theme}/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

And i have the classical start lines:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="2columns-right" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional">
```

but sublime said that it failed to locate the main schema resource at `'url:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd'`

And i don't know why this hapends

Answer (score 0):

> Magento code references all XSD schemas as Uniform Resource Names
>   (URNs). If you’re developing code and need to reference XSDs, this
>   command configures your integrated developer environment (IDE) to
>   recognize and highlight URNs. This makes development easier.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-urn.html